# MVP player embedded in PySide app not receiving mouse clicks on Windows

Tags: python, pyside, pyside2, mpv

I'm building a PySide/Qt based app that with video playback. I found [mpv player](https://www.mpv.io) and the helpful `python-mpv` library to get it into my Python based app. Everything works great. The issue I'm having is trying to use the player on a **Windows** machine (no issues on OS X): the player renders, the video starts playing, the sound works, but *I cannot CLICK on the on-screen controls*. The controls are visible, but clicking on them does nothing. It's as if the widget isn't receiving the mouse clicks, but only on Windows?

I haven't found much else around the internets trying to debug this. The player throws no errors or warnings, so it's hard to know where to start. I'm not normally a Windows dude, either. [This person seems to have had the same issue](https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/jaseg/python-mpv/103/581823159), but I'm not sure if they ever solved it.

Has anyone else had trouble or success getting mpv player to work inside a Qt-based app? Appreciate any insights! Same code I've been playing with below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
# In order to load mpv-1.dll
os.environ["PATH"] = os.path.dirname(__file__) + os.pathsep + os.environ["PATH"]

import mpv
import sys

from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
from PySide2.QtCore import *

class Test(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.container = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.container)
        self.container.setAttribute(Qt.WA_DontCreateNativeAncestors)
        self.container.setAttribute(Qt.WA_NativeWindow)

        player = mpv.MPV(wid=str(int(self.container.winId())),
                         input_default_bindings=True,
                         input_vo_keyboard=True)
        player.play('./sample-mp4-file.mp4')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # This is necessary since PyQT stomps over the locale settings needed by libmpv.
    # This needs to happen after importing PyQT before creating the first mpv.MPV instance.
    import locale
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, 'C')

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Test()
    win.setFixedWidth(1200)
    win.setFixedHeight(800)
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, and this is my solution. You can get the "mouse button" event from mpv and call a function.

```
@player.on_key_press('MOUSE_BTN0')
def mouse_pressed():
    print('mouse button pressed')
```